# How to print the number of duplicate elements in array in C

Tags: arrays, c, duplicates

any help would be greatly appreciated. In this code below, i understand that we need to use "j=i+1" because the same element in the original array and duplicate array should not get recorded as a duplicate element. But, lets say during the 2nd loop, when i=2,so j=3,then the loop will run from the 3rd element right? and how will it compare the 2nd element in the array with the 1 element in the duplicate? will it not miss the first element in the duplicate because it is j+1?
please explain this to me , I am a beginner in programming. and also, why is count++ used ?
can someone explain this to me ...?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_SIZE 100  // Maximum array size

int main()
{
    int arr[MAX_SIZE];
    int i, j, size, count = 0;

    /* Input size of array */
    printf("Enter size of the array : ");
    scanf("%d", &size);

    /* Input elements in array */
    printf("Enter elements in array : ");
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    }

    /*
     * Find all duplicate elements in array
     */
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        for(**j=i+1**; j<size; j++)
        {
            /* If duplicate found then increment count by 1 */
            if(arr[i] == arr[j])
            {
                **count++;**
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\nTotal number of duplicate elements found in array = %d", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ... array... **0th step: sort the array(s)**

Comment: @pmg what do you mean

Comment: Sorry for terseness. What I mean is, if you have a problem involving arrays, the very first thing to do is to sort the arrays. Sorting is `O(n.logn)`; will not impact the rest of the problem too much even if not absolutely required ... and you can remove the sorting if you find a solution in `O(n)`

Comment: If you sort the array, all the duplicates will be adjacent. This will simplify counting.

Comment: @pmg: “sort the array” is an advanced concept for somebody asking about simple loops and `count++`. Teaching needs to teach the student what is adjacent to what they already know, not things that are beyond what is currently visible to them.

Comment: Since nobody else seems interested in doing so... *"how will it compare the 2nd element in the array with the 1 element in the duplicate?"* - Consider how you got to the current iteration. When `i` is 2, that means you've already swept the array twice-prior, once starting at 0, again, starting at 1. E.g. that work was done in prior iterations.

Comment: I agree @EricPostpischil, sorry tiara. Nevertheless... tiara, keep a note in the back of your mind "sorted arrays are awesome" for the future =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to think about this. First, consider the code you have:

```
for(i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    for(j=i+1; j<size; j++)
    {
        /* If duplicate found then increment count by 1 */
        if(arr[i] == arr[j])
        {
            count++;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The statement `count++;` increments the value stored in `count`. The `break` ends the inner loop (at which point the outer loop continues and may start a different execution of the inner loop).

You can try this code on simple examples, such as [1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 2], and [1, 2, 1]. What results do you get?

Next, try it on [1, 1, 1] or [1, 2, 1, 3, 1]. What results do you get? What result do you want?

Can you describe a characteristic of the situations in which the code produces a result different from what you want?

Once you have done that, can you think of a solution? What is the code doing that you want it not to do?

Comment: Posting this answer makes me think we have to close the question as too broad. This answer is not an answer in that it does not give a solution to the question asked in the title—how to count the duplicates. But being handed a solution is not what the student needs at this point. They need to learn how to use code in various ways and how to think about problems and their solutions. That is what this answer aims for, but that is not what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: thank you very much, i figured it out once I got calm,

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question (hope I understand it well):

- When `i == 0`, you compare first element with all other elements - either you find some duplicates or you don't.
- When `i == 1`, you compare second element with all elements except the first one - you don't need to compare with first because **you've already done it** in previous step.
- Etc..

Comment: But we have not compared the second element with the first element right?why is that?

Comment: An issue they have to deal with is in, say, [1, 2, 1, 3, 1]. Then `a[0]` equals `a[2]` and is counted as a duplicate, and `a[2]` equals `a[4]` and is counted as another duplicate.

Comment: @tiara You did compare it when i == 0 and j == 1, you don't need to compare it again. In other words you don't need state when i == 1 and j == 0.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to sort the array and don't want to use any hash map.
Here is the solution :

```
int dup(int a[],int n){
int count=0;
int i=0;
int j=0;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<n;j++){
        if( a[i]==a[j] && j!=i){
            if(j>i){
                count++;
            }   
            break;
        }
    }
}
return count;
```

}